# Automate Google Takeout Download

Tags: automation, google-api, puppeteer

Is there a way to programmatically initiate/schedule google takeout download(all 46+ services) data

https://takeout.google.com/

I would like to take regular backups of this data (Local or Google Drive)

Can `Puppeteer` be used to automate user clicks in the absence of an API from Google?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: did you ever made the script for this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it definitely is possible. I would recommend using a headless browser such as Selenium or Puppeteer. There are are a few steps in order to accomplish this:

1) automate logging in to Google (if need be)
2) automate navigating to Google Takeout and downloading data
3 parse the data
4) write a script so you can automate this whole process on a regular basis.

There are a also a few things to be aware of when writing a web scraper:

When running a browser in headless mode, the the HTML served can differ from a browser run non-headless. In other words the attributes on the DOM elements can be named differently, and since you use these attributes to automate things like selecting and clicking - your code will need to change. For this reason, inspecting the elements through your browser is a good place to start, but you will likely need to adjust the the names of your attributes when running in headless mode, which so be of help for getting started on this. For example, the following code excerpts show the same code for logging into Google written two ways for Puppeteer. One is written headless and one is written non-headless:

Headless Mode:

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://takeout.google.com');


    await page.waitForSelector('input[type=email]')
    await page.type('input[type=email]', process.env.GOOGLE_USER)
    await page.click('#next')

    await page.waitForSelector('#Passwd', { visible: true })
    await page.type('#Passwd', process.env.GOOGLE_PWD);
    await page.waitForSelector('#signIn', { visible: true })
    await page.click('#signIn');

    await page.waitForNavigation()
    await browser.close();

})();
```

Non-Headless Mode:

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 50 })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://takeout.google.com');


    await page.waitForSelector('input[type="email"]')
    await page.type('input[type="email"]', process.env.GOOGLE_USER)
    await page.click('#identifierNext')

    await page.waitForSelector('input[type="password"]', { visible: true })
    await page.type('input[type="password"]', process.env.GOOGLE_PWD)
    await page.waitForSelector('#passwordNext', { visible: true })
    await page.click('#passwordNext')


    await page.waitForNavigation()
    await browser.close()
})()
```